# How to run timer and AI logic in Swift simultaneously

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, artificial-intelligence, nstimer

I have an NSTimer() and an AI logic for a board game. The AI logic takes long time to process about 3 to 5 seconds(which is ok). When the program is executing the AI logic, the NSTimer doesn't fire until the AI logic finished it's execution.

This is how i started the timer during the initial stage of the game.

```
    public var timer = NSTimer()
```

...

```
    let timeSelector:Selector = "timerFired"
    if self.useTime {
       timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: timeSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

I added the AI logic in Update of an SKScene so that when it detects it is his turn, he will start checking for available moves

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
      if gameStatus.playerTurn == "AI" && !aiThiking {
         aiThiking = true
         aIPlayer.aiCheckAvaialbleMoves()
         // executeMove
         // change Turn
         aiThiking = false
      }
```

My question is, is it possible to let the AI logic execute and let the timer still running at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that `aIPlayer.aiCheckAvailableMoves()` freezes the app as long as it takes to execute, so `NSTimer` does not work as it should. You can use different `threads` to avoid this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    aIPlayer.aiCheckAvaialbleMoves()
}
```

This code runs this function in a new thread and when the code ended, the thread is closed automatically.

You could use completion blocks to know exactly when the function ended. Here is an example:

```
func aiCheckAvailableMoves(completion : (result : BOOL) -> Void) {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
       //Do your code normally

       //When you have finished, call the completion block (like a return)
       completion(true)
   }
}
```

And then, from your `update:` you will get when the function ended (please note here there is no `dispatch_async`):

```
aIPlayer.aiCheckAvailableMoves(){
    //Finished checking moves, maybe schedule again?
}
```

Be careful with threads, as they can cause unwanted behaviour or/and crashes!

Comment: thank you. I will consider multi-threading. I'm new to swift. So i don't know how it works. I need to be able to check if this process was finished and/or stop the thread and start a new one. Is this possible? if yes, I will try to search for sources about multi-threading in Swift.

Comment: Check again my answer, I think it will help you better ;)

Comment: good! thank you so much. it seems working. as expected, my code crash and behave abnormally but its ok. i'm sure can figure out how to adjust them. at least my syncing issues are solved.